# Google Cloud Shell Tutorial displays Tutorial ID not valid: RESERVED_ID:PACKAGED_TUTORIAL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

When launching the following [tutorial](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor?cloudshell_image=gcr.io/cloudshell-images/cloudshell&cloudshell_git_repo=https://github.com/spurin/diveintoansible-lab-gcp-cloudshell.git&cloudshell_tutorial=tutorial.md&shellonly=true) via Google Cloud Shell, myself and others are intermittently seeing the following popup -

[Tutorial ID not valid: RESERVED_ID:PACKAGED_TUTORIAL: IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdzTX.png)

Then, the tutorial disappears.  If I run `teachme tutorial.md` it reappears.  When checking the browser console, it appears that a resource required by Cloud Shell is unavailable and within this, is a reference to the text shown in the error -

[404 for walkthroughs.googleusercontent.com: IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwPHi.png) - the full url is:

https://walkthroughs.googleusercontent.com/content/RESERVED_ID:PACKAGED_TUTORIAL/RESERVED_ID:PACKAGED_TUTORIAL.md?additional_params=cloudcodedevsessionenable

If I try the same tutorial in another Google account with an incognito window, it doesn't get the same error.  However, in the console it is repeatedly lopping with 302 cors failed requests -

[302 cors failed: IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72PEL.png)

It may be that there are two separate issues here.  If anyone has any advice on how/if I'm able to troubleshoot this further it would be appreciated.  If anyone who manages Google Cloud Shell is reviewing these questions, am happy to provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be fixed. Could you try again now?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).